# Constructing a matrix with given properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a fairly simple question here.

> a) Give an example of a $3 \times 4$  matrix $A$ and a $3 \times 1$ vector $\vec{b}$ such that the solution set of the linear system with the augmented matrix $[A|\vec{b}]$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^4$ which has a direction vector $\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ -2 \\ 1 \\0\end{bmatrix}$.

> b) Give an example of a $3 \times5$ matrix $A$ such that the linear system $[A|\vec{b}]$ has at least one solution for every vector $\vec{b}$ of size $3 \times1$.

Is there any method to do this aside from guessing? I feel like there should be a systematic method...

Comment: Let $\vec{v} = [3 \ -2 \ 1 \ 0]^T$. a) asks for examples of $A$ and $\vec{b}$ that will make the equation $A\vec{v} = \vec{b}$ true. You can either choose a simple $A$ or $\vec{b}$ and solve for the other.

Comment: Yes I got it. Thank you.